# How can I determine if an object of anonymous type is empty?

Tags: c#, .net

I am sure the answer to this is quite simple but I am trying to write an if statement (C# 5.0) to determine whether or not an anonymous type is empty or not. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
public void DoSomething(object attributes)
{
    // This is the line I need??
    if (atrributes != new {}) {

    }
}
```

The attributes variable gets created dynamically depending on what is needed and sometimes it is empty.

So how do I determine if an anonymous type is empty?

Comment: Check if its `null`?

Comment: Since anonymous types do not provide an `==` operator overload, perhaps you mean `object.Equals(htmlAttributes, new { })`.

Comment: I would rather prefer to write a class with a an appropriate builder and build the object depending on your needs. And if you don't have any properties set just create a so called [Null Object](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/null_object) or return `null`.

Comment: @Loocid Null doesn't work.

Comment: But @Mike z your code works. Thanks!!

Comment: @Loocid: An empty object is not the same as null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anonymous types do not provide operator overloads for `==`, although it wouldn't matter in this case since one of the arguments is typed object. However the C# compiler does provide Equals, GetHashCode, and ToString implementations.

Use the static `object.Equals`, method which will do the appropriate null checks and then call the virtual Equals method on the first argument:

```
object.Equals(attributes, new { });
```

You could also cache a static instance if you were concerned about the overhead of an allocation for each comparison.

Answer (score 2):

If by empty you mean no properties, you can use reflection:

```
var o1 = new {};
o1.GetType().GetProperties().Count(); //==0

var o2 = new {test=1};
o2.GetType().GetProperties().Count(); //==1
```